# Meaning of "eyes well up"

Tags: word-meaning

I found the following sentence in an article:

> > Chaaya becomes very happy when she finds that her son is still alive. Her **eyes well up**.

What is the meaning of **"eyes well up"**? I tried to check this in the Oxford dictionary, but there I found a close meaning:

> > [**well up** no object, with adverbial (of a liquid) **rise up to the surface and spill or be about to spill.**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/well)
> >
> > ‘tears were beginning to **well up** in her eyes’

But I nowhere found **"eyes well up"** in any of these 3 dictionaries: Oxford, Cambridge, Merriam-webster. I also checked this through [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyes%20well%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceyes%20well%20up%3B%2Cc0) and found that this is commonly used nowadays. I am not able to understand whether this combination of words **"eyes well up"** has any meaning?

Comment: Here "eye" as a subject doesn't appear appropriate. It should be "tears well up"

Comment: Eyes filled with tears as a (dug) well fills with water, or as any water source below ground rises to the surface.

Comment: @abhijeetpathak "tears welled up in his eyes" is also appropriate. The phrase "her eyes welled up (with tears)" is a bit more idiomatic but still appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that a person's eyes are filling up with tears, and the tears are about to spill out. In other words, the person is about to cry.

"Eyes *tear* up" has the same meaning, but it's not as flowery.